# Link to files in VSCode .ipynb notebooks

Tags: visual-studio-code, hyperlink, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I'm trying to put a link to a file in a markdown cell in a notebook, for example:

```
See [feature scaling notes](feature_scaling_notes.md)
```

The file `feature_scaling_notes.md` is in the same folder as the .ipynb file.

A link is created, yet when I click on it, instead of opening the file, a browser window is opened with the address:

```
https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-webview.net/...(file path)
```

How can I make the file open in the correct way?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps not an answer (I haven't tried it yet), but something I would suggest is putting the file protocol in your address, like this: `See [feature scaling notes](file://feature_scaling_notes.md)`

Comment: @RobJarvis That is not recognized as a link in the markdown preview. In the markdown editing mode it is recognized as a link but gives an error message when clicked: "Unable to open... File is a directory"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming in v1.63 are file links in notebooks, see [release note: file links in notebooks](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_63.md#file-links-in-notebooks).

> Markdown inside notebooks can now link to other files in the current
> workspace
>
> Links the start with `/` are resolved relative to the workspace root.
> Links that start with `./` or just start with a filename are resolved
> relative to the current notebook.

`[link text](./cat.gif)`

> #### Bare http(s) links notebooks
>
> In addition, markdown text that looks like an `http` and `https` is
> now automatically turned into a link: